# SupportMapFragment very slow when opening for second time

Tags: supportmapfragment

I tried to implement SupportMapFragment, but its very slow when opening for second time.

My XML - Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/hits_map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

MyFragmentActivity:

```
package com.example.mapsupporttest;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
public class MainActivitySupportTest extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity_support_test);
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what makes my map fragment loading slow?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26265526/what-makes-my-map-fragment-loading-slow)