# Loading a view from a fragment after the fragment's activity is visible

Tags: android, fragment, viewstub

I have a view (a google map), in a fragment, that takes very much of the UI thread, so i want to display the fragment with a ViewStub instead of the map view, and after the fragment is displayed, i'll inflate the viewStub layout.
Like this :

```
ViewStub stub = (ViewStub) view.findViewById(R.id.mapViewStub);
        View inflated = stub.inflate();
        mMapView = (MapView) inflated.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
```

The problem is that i don't know where to place the code above, in order to be executed after the fragment in displayed and to be executed just once.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by 'takes very much of the UI thread' ?

Comment: It slow down the UI thread. And the fragment is visible with a delay. So this is why i use view stub.

Comment: I think you can take some 'heat' off the UI thread by doing stuff asynchronously. Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26265526/what-makes-my-map-fragment-loading-slow